# How to change angular md-datepicker icon's aria-label="Open calendar" in other language?

Tags: angular, angular-material

[Here I have created angular md-datepicker demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-datepicker-demo)

> I want to change/translate the angular md-datepicker icon's aria-label="Open calendar" text shown in the below image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Create a Service.

```
import { MatDatepicker } from '@angular/material';
import { CustomTranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

const OPEN_CALENDAR = 'Open Calendar';

@Injectable()
export class CustomMatDatePickerService extends MatDatepicker {
    public constructor(private translate: CustomTranslateService) {
    super();

    this.translate.onLangChange.subscribe((e: Event) => {
        this.getAndInitTranslations();
    });

    this.getAndInitTranslations();
    }
    openCalendarLabel = this.translate.translations[this.translate.store.currentLang][OPEN_CALENDAR];
    public getAndInitTranslations(): void {
        this.translate.get([
            OPEN_CALENDAR
        ])
        .subscribe((translation: any) => {
            this.openCalendarLabel = translation[OPEN_CALENDAR];
            this.changes.next();
        });
    }
}
```